# how to get all column names in SSAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence

In Sql Server we will get all column names by using

```
Select * from Informationschema.columns
```

to get all column names

In SSAS how can we get all column names for any cube
we an see by clicking on browse in Tree Format but how can we achieve in MDX Query

please suggest me SSAS is new area for me

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT [CATALOG_NAME] as [DATABASE],
      CUBE_NAME AS [CUBE],[DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] AS [DIMENSION],
      LEVEL_CAPTION AS [ATTRIBUTE],
      [LEVEL_NAME_SQL_COLUMN_NAME] AS [ATTRIBUTE_NAME_SQL_COLUMN_NAME],
      [LEVEL_KEY_SQL_COLUMN_NAME] AS [ATTRIBUTE_KEY_SQL_COLUMN_NAME]
FROM $system.MDSchema_levels
WHERE CUBE_NAME  ='Adventure Works'
AND level_origin=2
AND LEVEL_NAME <> '(All)'
order by [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME]
```

[Source](https://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/ssas-dmv-queries-cube-metadata/)

Comment: how can we use ORDER BY [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME],LEVEL_CAPTION and like condition in SSAS

Comment: your are query is quite helpful can you tell me how to use ORDER by for more than one column and like condition

Comment: You may also need SELECT * FROM $system.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES to list the measures. I think the above just lists dimension levels.

Comment: LEVEL_NAME_SQL_COLUMN_NAME gives you something like NAME($DimDate].[Month] and will be the same as [LEVEL_KEY_SQL_COLUMN_NAME. This means it doesn't give you the actual key and name columns. It seems NAME() is a DMX function but I can't figure out how to use it as every usage I can think of throws the error 'The function cannot be used in the context at line 1, column 174.'